# Trouble avoiding computation in DynamicModule when input field is not defined

Tags: dynamic

I'm having trouble detecting when my InputForm supplied String variable has a value.  After looking at:

[How to compute values only if input fields are filled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30660/how-to-compute-values-only-if-input-fields-are-filled)

I tried a StringQ test:

```
Clear[foo]
foo[t_] := If [ StringQ[t], {t, "defined"}, {t, "undefined"} ]

DynamicModule[{symbol},
 Column[{
   Row[{"Text field:", InputField[Dynamic[symbol], String]}],
   foo[ Dynamic[symbol] ]
   } ]
 ]
```

Before the field is supplied this gives me what I expected:

[image: before field keyed]

but after keying the field, I see that my test hasn't worked:

[image: after keying text]

Based on

[How can I make sure all InputFields have values before processing a nb form?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6622/how-can-i-make-sure-all-inputfields-have-values-before-processing-a-nb-form)

I tried:

```
Clear[foo]
foo[t_] := If [ !Equal[t, ""], {t, "defined"}, {t, "undefined"} ]

DynamicModule[{symbol = ""},
 Column[{
   Row[{"Text field:", InputField[Dynamic[symbol], String]}],
   foo[ Dynamic[symbol] ]
   } ]
 ]
```

but this produces a kind of odd unevaluated If block:

[image: other try]

I'm clearly doing something wrong with how I'm testing or using the input variable or form, but it's not obvious to me what that is?

Comment: it's a simple mistake: `Dynamic@foo[symbol]`, `Dynamic` gives head. Try `StringQ[Dynamic["test"]]`

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate, but the issue seems to be the wrong use of `Dynamic`, the code will do what is expected when using `Dynamic[foo[symbol]]` instead of `foo[Dynamic[symbol]]` and that isn't explained in the linked duplicate question IMO. The best answer I could find seems to be John Fultz's to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1179430/1159366), which I think would be a better duplicate link, but probably someone knows a good candidate on ME...

Answer (score 0):

As canvassed often here it is better practice to stick your functions in initialization. Additionally it is best to think about `Dynamic` as updating pixels on the screen. So find the expression that gets rendered on the screen and then wrap it in `Dynamic`. The code below works fine:

```
DynamicModule[{symbol = Null},
 Column[{
   Row[{"Text field:", InputField[Dynamic[symbol], String]}],
   Dynamic@foo[symbol]
   }],
 Initialization :> {foo[t_] := 
    If[StringQ[t], {t, "defined"}, {t, "undefined"}]}
 ]
```